zipping lists creates duplicates under certain inputs
I have a function that creates a grid given a bounding box. I recently came across a situation where under certain conditions the zip call ends up returning a number much lower than the expected permutations of the inputs.
Consider the following MWE:
import numpy as np

def makegrid(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
  
  xmin = int(np.floor(xmin / 1000) * 1000)
  ymin = int(np.floor(ymin / 1000) * 1000)
  xmax = int(np.ceil(xmax / 1000) * 1000)
  ymax = int(np.ceil(ymax / 1000) * 1000)
  
  left_list = [ left for bottom in range(ymin, ymax, 1000) for left in range(xmin, xmax, 1000) ]
  bottom_list = [ bottom for left in range(xmin, xmax, 1000) for bottom in range(ymin, ymax, 1000) ]
  
  right_list = [left + 1000 for left in left_list]
  top_list = [bottom + 1000 for bottom in bottom_list]
  
  #edit - add print statement showing input dims
  print(f"dims: {len(left_list)}, {len(bottom_list)}, {len(right_list)}, {len(top_list)}")

  zip_coords = zip(left_list,bottom_list,right_list,top_list)
  zcoords = list(zip_coords)
  
  print(f"expecting: {len(set(left_list)) * len(set(bottom_list))} tiles")
  print(f"produced: {len(set(zcoords))} tiles")



#example one - works correctly
makegrid(452958.56 , 3684771.695,  551076.93 , 3846044.225)

#expecting: 16300
#produced: 16300

#example two - does not work and produces a fraction of expected
makegrid(518249.995, 3630269.23 ,  638616.78 , 3816623.475)

#expecting: 22627
#produced: 2057


#example three - add some jitter to example two, back to working correctly
makegrid(518249.995, 3640269.23 ,  640616.78 , 3856623.475)

#expecting: 26691
#produced: 26691

#example four - a different jitter, does not match
makegrid(519249.995, 3630169.23 ,  638516.78 , 3812623.475)

#expecting: 21960 
#produced: 7320


I have verified that each input list is the same size. I have also tried adding a strict=True param to the zip call but I cannot figure out why the zip function is collapsing the entries down.

zip returns a sequence whose length is the smallest of the inputs you give it.

You can use itertools.zip_longest() to return a sequence whose length is the longest of the inputs.

The input list comprehensions are all identical lengths. I would expect if that was the issue then adding the strict=True param to error out.

zip() doesn't create permutations.

you use set() which removes similar values - and this can makes problem

you should display print( len(set(left_list)) ) and print( len(set(bottom_list) ). Or even display len(left_list),len(bottom_list), len(zcoords)without usingset()`

It's not clear why you are using zip in the first place. Isn't product(range(xmin, xmax, 1000), range(ymin, ymax, 1000)) what you want?

My use of set in the above example was simply to illustrate that it is producing less tiles than I am expecting, I realize that it is removing duplicates.

Your function is overly complicated. All you want is the cartesian product of the two ranges; use itertools.product for that, rather than zipping together two multisets.
def makegrid(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):

  xmin = int(np.floor(xmin / 1000) * 1000)
  ymin = int(np.floor(ymin / 1000) * 1000)
  xmax = int(np.ceil(xmax / 1000) * 1000)
  ymax = int(np.ceil(ymax / 1000) * 1000)

  x_coords = range(xmin, xmax, 1000)
  y_coords = range(ymin, ymax, 1000)

  return list(product(x_coords, y_coords)) 

You can also use a list comprehension directly:
return [(x, y) for x in x_coords for y in y_coords]


Yes, this does produce the correct output but so does my examples 1 + 3 from above
Cleanliness aside, what I am really trying to understand is why the snippet above fails on examples 2 and 4 specifically while simultaneously working correctly on 1 and 3?
This does output the correct grid on all four, so I will mark as answered shortly

The problem is likely in how you are computing the four <direction>_lists, but since their use is far more complicated than simply computing a cartesian product from x_coords and y_coords directly, I'm not interested in figuring out where the error is.
